# How to check out spesific revision using GitPython?

Tags: python, gitpython

I want to check out a spesific revision of a git repo. How to do this using GitPython?

```
# GitPython==1.0.1
from git import Repo

r = Repo.clone_from(git_url, repo_dir)
#r.checkout(revision)  # How to do this?
```

Comment: Just like that you have commented out.

Comment: Repo has no function checkout